# As + Adjective only

Tags: adjectives

> The prices *at* The Economy Center *are* as reasonable, *if not more* reasonable, *as* those at comparable to the United States.

The words in italics are the possible mistakes according to my book. I think that *as reasonable* must be followed with an *as*, what's wrong here?

Comment: Now that the question is being reopened, you could edit it deleting "Nope, this isn't an assignment. UPDATE:"

Comment: @Carlo_R. Okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s something wrong or missing in the last part of the sentence. As for the first part, there’s a problem with following a comparative adjective, *more reasonable*, with *as*. There are a number of ways of dealing with this, such as:

*The prices at The Economy Center are as reasonable as, if not more reasonable than, those . . .*

*The prices at The Economy Center are at least as reasonable as those . . .*

*The prices at The Economy Center are as reasonable as those . . . if not more so.*

Comment: I think in such constructions it's perfectly okay to use the preposition appropriate to the *last* of the preceding elements *(...as reasonable, if not more reasonable **than**...)*. Not much of a sample size, but Google Books finds 10 instances of that phrasing, against only 4 for OP's quoted version with *"...if not more reasonable **as**..."*. Certainly *"as good if not better **as**"* is far less common than *"as good if not better **than**"*.